# Better way of handling isset/!empty?

Tags: php

```
$controller = new UserController();

if (isset($_POST['submitform']))
{   
    $validated = false;

    $inputs = array (
        'username', 'email', 'password',
        'repassword', 'password_f', 'repassword_f',
        'display'
    );

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($inputs as $key)
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$key]) && !empty($_POST[$key]))
        {
            $i++;
            if ((int)$i == count($inputs))
            {
                $validated = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                $controller->error = "";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($validated)
    {
        echo 2;
    }
}
```

So let's overview the code.

First we are checking if the form was submitted.

Then we are creating a new `boolean $validated` and setting it `false` by default.

Then we created our array with the `POST` names.

Now the checking part, setting variable `int i` to `0` by default.
Now we are looping through the array elements.

Checking if the current `index` was set or not `empty`, if yes, `add +1 to int $i`.

Once int `$i` hits the number of counted elements of our array, set `$validated` to `true`, and break out of the array, else parse error and break out.

Then we are checking, if `bool $validated` is true, then echo 2.

***Is it a good way of doing this? Is there any cleaner/better way?***

Comment: I would discourage you from using flags. Don't set `$validated` in the first place, instead, when you need to, just call the desired function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this instead:

```
function validateForm() {
    if (!isset($_POST['submitform']))
        return false; // Maybe $controller->error = "Something"; as well?
    $inputs = array (
        'username', 'email', 'password',
        'repassword', 'password_f', 'repassword_f',
        'display'
    );
    foreach ($inputs as $key)
        if (empty($_POST[$key]))
        {
            global $controller;
            $controller->error = "";
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}
...
if (valudateForm()) {
    echo 2;
} else {
    // Form data not ok
}
```

Seems cleaner, no flags, no counting array elements, validation has its own function,...

Comment: Although your answer is pretty close to what I would do, I can't upvote it with the `global` in it :) (Maybe just return the keys of the invalid input and build the error message in the controller)

Comment: global is good if used properly. Look at Drupal core. They use global all over the place, but that doesn't make it bad code...

Comment: @mnhg Global variables can make all kinds of chaos, I agree. However, the above doesn't seem like a reusable code, but rather a single script, in which `$controller` seems like something common for the whole site. I see no problem `global`-ing something in such case, and I believe that nothing sould ever be discarded as "generally wrong" without addressing the exact situation. If you have a problem with `global` in here, I'd love to hear it (possibly learning something useful).

Comment: @Vedran Nip it in the bud. It is unnecessarily hard to write isolated test with globals and do be sure to don't mess thinks up with new tests or a change to a global. This is no local script, but a web page, so no need for hacking.

Comment: @Pinoniq I'm not familiar with Drupal in detail. Do you have any articles about testing-best-practice in Drupal in relation to globals?

Comment: Anyone mentioning Drupal as any kind of code quality measurement has no clue what they're talking about. Not only is Drupal one of the worst applications ever developed, it's notoriously slow and awful to use. Using `global` is always a bad idea, without exception. You'll use it once, then twice, then a next guy joins in and you have a nice mess. If you require a variable / object that exists outside the scope of a function, pass it along as a parameter. It's much cleaner and easier to understand where it came from.

Comment: So, basically, `global` is bad because you cannot control yourself to use it only when it really makes sense? For example, if a PHP script is a part of a web site never to be included anywhere else, why would I pass a PDO object all the time? I'd `global` it and use it, no more different than superglobals like `$_POST` (apart from them not needing `global`). And the above `$controller` seems to be exactly that kind of variable. If it's not, I agree that the OP should pass it as an argument, but I will not diss anything just because some programmers cannot make a proper per-case judgement.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not a real validation here. The check is: are all required fields filled with some value? Please notice that all modern browsers can use the 'required' attribute in formfields and will not post a form while not all required fields are filled. But double checking server-side is of course always good practice.
Please, keep functions as clean as possible. They only have to do **one** thing. So: no error-messages in the function etc. Only return true or false. That way, you can re-use your function. So I think this simple function will do just fine.

```
<?php
/**
 * Check if all required fields are filled
 *  
 * @param array $post the POST array
 * @param array $fieldsArray an array with values to check
 * @return boolean
 */
function filledRequiredFields($post, $fieldsArray)
{
    foreach($fieldsArray as $key)
    {
        if(empty($post[$key]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    $inputs = array(
        'username', 'email', 'password',
        'repassword', 'password_f', 'repassword_f',
        'display'
    );

    if (filledRequiredFields($_POST, $inputs))
    {
        echo 2;
    }
    else 
    {
        //etc.
    }
}
```